# Why is $|a-b|^2=|a|^2-2a\cdot b+|b|^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I was reading a proof for the trigonometric definition of the dot product of vector **a** and vector **b**, and it involved the following $$|a-b|^2=|a|^2-2a\cdot b+|b|^2$$

I don't understand why the absolute values remain from $a\cdot a$ and $b\cdot b$ but not $a\cdot b$. Why is that the case?

Comment: I think there should be a dot between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Don’t write $2ab$ when you mean $2a\cdot b.$ $|a|$ is by definition $\sqrt{a\cdot a},$ so we sometimes write $|a|^2$ for $a\cdot a.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot product is defined as
$$\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}=|\mathbf{a}| |\mathbf{b}|\cos\theta$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors.

On expanding the expression, we get
$$(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b})^2=\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{a}+2(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b})+\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{b}$$
Now, notice that every vector is parallel to itself (*i.e.* makes angle $\theta=0$), and so the $\cos\theta$ in the product vanishes (and it does NOT necessarily happen for different vectors). Thus,
$$(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b})^2=|\mathbf{a}|^2+2(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b})+|\mathbf{b}|^2$$
Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: +1 for "...every vector is parallel to itself...and it does NOT necessarily happen for different vectors..." that is what made click for me, thank you

Answer (score 2):

We have $|a| = \sqrt{\langle a,a \rangle}$ and $|b| = \sqrt{\langle b,b \rangle}$, where $\langle\;,\rangle$ is the dot product. So what this actually says is:
$$\langle a-b ,a-b \rangle = \langle a ,a \rangle - 2\langle a ,b \rangle + \langle b ,b \rangle\\
|a-b|^2=|a|^2-2\langle a, b \rangle +|b|^2$$

The norm is just the square root of the dot product of a vector with itself. Focus less on the norm and more on the dot product.

Comment: Hi, I'm curious -- why are the components of $\left< \ , \right>$ missing?

Comment: I was just referring to the operation. As in "$\langle\;,\rangle$ is the dot product, $\langle a, b \rangle$ is the  dot product of $a$ and $b$".